# How to set getExternalStorageState()

Tags: root-access, external-sd, internal-sd

I have rooted a [B&N Nook Glowlight](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/nook-glowlight-barnes-noble/1114959612) running Android 2.1. The device does not come with an SD card, so I symlinked to another directory from `/sdcard/`. Now I need to set the `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` value so that apps will be able to find the "card". How does one set this value?

Note that other devices, such as the [Nexus S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_S), also do not have an SD Card, yet they do return a `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` value for applications that require it.

**Note that I am not writing an Android application which uses this value. I need to set this value device-wide so that other applications (such as [Anki](https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/) and [Opera](http://www.opera.com/mobile) will be able to find it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for eclair's `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eclair-sholes-release2/core/java/android/os/Environment.java).  It looks like `getExternalStorageState()` comes to this:

`return SystemProperties.get("EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE", MEDIA_REMOVED)`

I think you want to take a look at the `/system/build.prop` file and check for a line like:

`EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE=removed`

If it's there, try changing it to:

`EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE=mounted`

To do this, `adb pull /system/build.prop`, modify the file on your computer, then `adb remount` to make `/system` writable (or `adb shell`, `su`, `mount -o rw,remount /system`)... then exit back to your computer and `adb push build.prop /system/build.prop` to push the modified file to `/system`).  Then reboot.

You can try temporarily (from root shell):

`setprop EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE mounted`

...if that works, you might then programmatically try:

`SystemProperties.set("EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE", Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);`

Hope this works out for ya.

Comment: Thank you! I am able to temporarily set the external storage as mounted via `setprop EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE mounted`. I'm trying to get the ADB working to set it permanently. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Comment: Yes, thank you! I still haven't resolved the entire issue, as this is a rooted B&N nook running Android 2.1, but you've put me on the right track.